# C programming Calc

Tags: c

I am trying to make a simple calculator in c as i want to test my programming skills. I keep getting a error though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calc()
{
    int *fnum;
    int *snum;
    printf("Enter your First Number: ");
    scanf("%d", fnum);

    printf("Enter your Second Number: ");
    scanf("%d", snum);

    int answer = *fnum + *snum;
    printf("%d", answer);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int *calcType;
    printf("Type of Calculation: 1=A, 2=S, 3=M, 4=D: ");
    scanf("%d", calcType);
    if (*calcType == 1)
    {
        calc();
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

But Then i get this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please help, i have no idea what this means.

Comment: So, you want to know what that error means? Look it up!

Comment: Remove the `*` from all of your variable delarations, to start. You don't need to be declaring pointers to int; you want int variables instead. Your C is really rusty; you should go back to your book or ask your teacher for help.

Comment: Consider `int x; some_function(x);` `x` has not been initialized nor assigned.   What value does `some_function()` receive? It is not defined and so leads to problems.  The same thing is happening with `scanf("%d", calcType);`,  `calcType` has not been assigned nor initialize.  Is is a pointer with no assigned value.

Comment: The most immediate problem is `calcType` pointing to a random address, into which he writes user input.

Answer (score 3):

You called `scanf` to read an integer into the memory pointed to by `calcType`, but you never set `calcType` to point to a valid address.

Answer (score 2):

Where the snum and fnum (int * pointers) point to? you have to declare a variable and pass its address (by reference operator &) to scanf.

The code should be something like this

```
int calc(){
    int fnum;
    int snum;
    printf("Enter your First Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &fnum);

    printf("Enter your Second Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &snum);

    int answer = fnum + snum;
    printf("%d", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

Also same problem with calcType pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be inputing `int`s, not `int*` (`int` **pointers**):

```
int fnum; /* This is now an int */
int snum; /* so is this */
printf("Enter your First Number: ");
scanf("%d", &fnum); /* Note that fnum's address is passed */

printf("Enter your Second Number: ");
scanf("%d", &snum); /* Same for snum */

int answer = fnum + snum;
printf("%d", answer);
return 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

That is a generic error message. You are incorrectly using pointers for fnum and snum, and attempting to add their addresses in memory.

Comment: "attempting to add their addresses in memory.", what now? Using `fnum` and `snum` would be totally fine if they had some allocated memory of type `*fnum`/`*snum` they pointed to.

Answer (score -2):

You missed

> &
>   Without it the programm wont know where to storage the data

```
scanf("%d", &fnum);
```

I also dont understand why you put

> *

Comment: That's not what he missed and the `*` is a deference. The issue is that the pointers are invalid, leading to undefined behaviour(The op is lucky to have gotten a descriptive runtime error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. ) upon deference and assign.

Comment: This looks more like a question than an answer.